# i am beginner and just started learning c++ and i am using eclipse [Version: Helios Service Release 2 Build id: 20110218-0911] on windows 10 64 bit pc

Tags: c++, eclipse, 64-bit

i have created a project folder in E:/ drive and run the existing file. but after creating a file by my own it sometime shows binary error and sometime shows the text output of the first file of that project instead of showing the output of my current file.....no idea please give me a clear idea of files,folders,projects,directories also to realise what is actually happening out there.

Comment: You need to add some details of exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Also note that Eclipse Helios is extremely old.